# What is the meaning of "needs his space..." on this comic page?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Marshall needs his space to move freely." Could you explain what the bar keeper implies? One of the comic readers said, that this phrase implies a gunfight, which marshall Sykes should be expected shortly  to. Is that a right guess? Because I don't get why Sykes needs his space for the gunfight. He is the best "trigger" in this story.  [image][image]

[image]

Comment: It's right there in the story: it means he doesn't want "company", and "doesn't like to be disturbed". It is also demonstrated with how rudely he tells the prostitute to leave him alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is means is that "he needs his space [in order] to move freely". If a gunfight starts, he doesn't want anybody standing in his way, as this would make it harder for him to avoid incoming gunfire.